# Syntax highlighting not working on Stm32CubeIde and Darkest Dark Theme

Tags: syntax, themes, highlight, stm32cubeide

I've just installed STM32CubeIDE 1.11.0 on a new Windows 11 machine. Then i install Darkest Dark Theme.

After restart i get the error "no editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.cdt.ui.editor.ceditor" and all source files have lost their syntax highlighting and the symbol in the project explorer has changed to the one for text files.

I've trid to reinstall STM32CubeIDE and install the previous version with no luck.

On my labtop with Windows 11 and STM32CubeIDE 1.11.0 it works no problem.

Anybody have a idea how to get syntax highlighting back?

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with stm32cubeide updated from v1.9.0 to v1.11.0, but a problem occurs if v1.11.0 is newly installed.

:) Interim solution (:<\br>
Untick the CDT url from the Available Software Sites list, and install DevStyle (from https://community.st.com/s/feed/0D53W00001zNKigSAG)